# How will I make this sequence correct in using c program

Tags: c

I want to print a sequence of 1 4 9 16 25...n by inputting any number which is equal to the number of terms I want as an output.
For example: if I input 4, it should print 1 4 9 16
but I can't seem to get the result I want using this program I have made. The result goes like 0 1 4 9.  I want to eliminate the first term zero, Can someone pls help me see what's wrong with my program?

```
int result,n;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
   scanf("%d", &n);
   printf("%d ", result); 
   result = pow(i,2);
}
```

Comment: Read the value of `n` *before* the loop, and print the result *after* you calculate it.

Comment: And also calculate `result` *before* you print it. And `pow()` returns a `double`, not an `int`. You would likely better off using `i*i` than using `pow()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int result, i, n;
    printf("Input n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        result = i*i;
        printf("%-3d", result);
    }
}

OUTPUT: 1   4   9   16... n^2
```

Probably, you want this.

You should scan the value of `n` before the loop. Otherwise, the behavior of your program would be unpredictable. Second, it is wise to avoid floating-point calculations when possible and here you want to print the series of square of integers. i.e. `1,4,9,...` so you shouldn't use

> `double pow(double a, double b)`

function. Also as Fred said, *"Calculate `result` before you print it."*